# What would be the best method to notify user of requirements before entering password?

Tags: android

I have an app where a user has to register to gain access. When the user enters a password there is a strength analysis bar bellow guiding them on weak, poor, good and strong passwords. However, I want to be able to inform the user of the requirements which are as follows:

- Use uppercase letters,
- Use lowercase letters,
- Use at least one character,
- Use at least one number and
- Minimum password length 8

I've looked into an alert dialog that I could trigger when the user clicks inside the edit text box. But I wanted to know if there were any other options I could use or if anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Your question is likely off-topic as it will most probably generate opinion-based answers. It may be better suited for https://ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try this,

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etText);
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
   //before enter text
   //write code to suggestion about password
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
});
```